# label not positioning correctly?

Tags: html, css

I have made a div of "alert box i am making". I can not position the text in the center of the title part. I have tried to add padding, and margins, but they do not work. http://jsfiddle.net/Hunter4854/9EPES/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the image out of the way with `position: absolute`, then simply use `text-align: center` to center the text: http://jsfiddle.net/9EPES/1/

Comment: i need that picture there. Is there any way i can keep the picture in the same spot i had it, but center the text.

Comment: I'm not suggesting to remove the picture from the box, just removing it from the "layout flow" with absolute positioning. The fiddle I linked to shows the picture, you just have to ajust the title bar height to accomodate it.

Comment: Oh! if i use position absolute, will the image stay there even if a person has a larger screen?

Comment: @EliteGamer Yes, provided the container has `position: relative` as I used in my fiddle. Then you can position the image with `left` and `top` properties.

Comment: so, i am using it as a popup, do i say "relative" or "absolute" i am confused?

Comment: `.titlex` should have `position: relative`, and `.titlex img` should have `position: absolute`. See [why](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/).